# Preloading images before webpage loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

it's my 1st question here, so pardon if something is asked wrong :)
 I want to preload 3 images before webpage is loaded so all of them would appear in the same moment. Right now images are loaded one after another and it looks kinda choppy. One image is defined in css (), other two are plain simple "img" element. I've tried creating javascript image objects - images still loads choppy, tried to preload them in display:none; div - still choppy. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention - images can't be merged or used as css sprite, 'cause 2 of them are user uploaded.

Comment: @egis I apologize, I didn't realize that the answer I gave was a solution to another problem. I guess I hadn't read your question good enough.

Comment: No problem. I'm surprised actually how much people came to help. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:  (try it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/186012/demos/loadatonce/index.html)

```
<!-- jQuery is required -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- the images -->
<div class="showmetoo" style="background: url(jimhance-vader_inset.jpg)">
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>

<img class="showall" src="octopus3.jpg" alt="a picture"><br/>
<img class="showall" src="moorea.jpg" alt="a picture"><br/>

<!-- hidden by default -->
<style>
img.showall { visibility: hidden }
div.showmetoo { visibility: hidden }
</style>



<!-- the script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var remaining = $('.showall').length;

function showthem(){
  remaining--;
  if(!remaining){
    $('.showall').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.showmetoo').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
}

// bind the callback to the load event of the pictures.
$('.showall').bind('load',showthem);

// force the pictures to show (just in case)
setTimeout(showthem, 1000);  //just in case load event fires before callback is set.
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to use data URIs http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/06/data-uris-make-css-sprites-obsolete/

I think that should probably fix it.

data URIs have some limitations as far as IE goes, but I think in this case you should just call it graceful degradation. :)

Edit: I saw your mention display:none divs. Display non divs will NOT preload your images. You need to set the display to block and hide the div in another way. Setting z-index or -9999 offset or some such.

Comment: Interesting, have not seen that before. But until < IE 7 dies it isnt an option if cross browser support is required.

Comment: @jdc0589 well it's pretty simple to specify normal urls for IE and uris for the rest.

Comment: Agreed. It does make me feel good to deprive IE users of a feature (seriously).

Comment: Good suggestion, but this can't be done. I only have means to edit html/css/jquery and those images are user uploaded (i can't write some php code that will convert them to base64). I need some css/javascript/jquery trick to load them before the page is loaded/displayed (if this is possible at all).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to display a loading gif for all three images until they are all loaded, then replace the gif with the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my image was very-high resolutions - more than what is needed for webpages - something like `4500 X 6000` - with a size of `~300kB`.  So, I adjusted the size with an image editing tool and watered the size down `400 X 600` with a size of `~50kB`.  Now the image loads quite fast and doesn't show a blank space while its loading.